Can't access smart cards from Windows service context
I'm enumerating certificates present on smart cards from a Windows service process. The API I'm using is a call to NCryptOpenStorageProvider to open the smart card provider, followed by enumerating the keys using NCryptEnumKeys.
If I run the service with a normal user account, everything works fine. If I run the service as Local System, NCryptEnumKeys returns SCARD_E_NO_SERVICE which is supposed to signal the Smart Card service is down. The error persists regardless of whether the smart card service is up or down.
Why is this not working for Local System? What's the best way to be able to enumerate the certs while running as Local System? Spawn another process as a local user to do the enumeration or just give up and run the service as a local user?

smart card visibility depend from terminal session. so and must be such result. in service - you need first impersonate user token. and call NCrypt api while impersonating. why service try access sc at all ? usually service is do something only based on user request. so service can impersonate user while do some work. enum cards in your case

also if you use NCryptEnumKeys - documentation say that pszScope - This parameter is not currently used and must be NULL. which is direct lie. it must be in form \.<readername>\ so format \.%s\ where readername from SCardListReadersW. only in case single reader in system - 0 is ok here

But I would need to install a user together with the service to impersonate them, right?

no of course. user (client) call service and you impersonate it during call
